# I cant load data json in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, loaddata

I have a problem loading my JSON data in the fragment

This method doesn't work

```
loadjson();
```

The Logcat is like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.asus.myapplication.fragment.kecamatan.Controller.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
                                               at com.example.asus.myapplication.fragment.kecamatan.KecamatanFragment.loadjson(KecamatanFragment.java:83)
                                               at com.example.asus.myapplication.fragment.kecamatan.KecamatanFragment.onCreateView(KecamatanFragment.java:47)
```

I don't know why. Can anyone help?

Here's the code

```
public class KecamatanFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String data_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/daftar/get_kecamatan.php"; // kasih link prosesnya

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager;
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<ModelData> mItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kecamatan, container, false);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_data);
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    mAdapter = new AdapterProcess(KecamatanFragment.this, mItems);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    loadjson();

    return view;
}

//proses mengambil data
private void loadjson(){
    pd.setMessage("Mengambil Data");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the rest of the loadJson method and where do you call `Controller.addToRequestQueue`? Your exception states that you are invoking the method `addToRequestQueue` on a null instance of `Controller`. It would appear that you need to instantiate your class `Controller` before calling `addToRequestQueue`.